# Embedding PDF into HTML without saving an actual file

Tags: php, html, pdf

**Question: Is it possible to embed PDF data on a HTML(5) page without linking to an actual on-server-disk PDF file.**

Background:
I just switched our webshop/erp system's documents to pdf files, which in general are de-facto for sending invoices, receipts, etc. by email.

Now i have this lovely preview/send document popup which shows the invoices, order confirmation etc., and allows staff to select one or more of them to send to customers. Previously i used html documents, which are easy to "embed" into my popup, but they are not such a good choice when it comes to sending them by email.

So i now changed all our documents to PDF files, which are both looking way better and don't get caught by trash filters as easily as html files.

Currently i save a file in my servers temporary directory and then embed it with this as part of my popup:

```
<object width="100%" height="100%" type="application/pdf" data="http://dev.foo.bar/temp/<rm-var document_filename>"></object>
```

This works, but it creates a "temp" file every time a document is opened in the popup. In our production environment this can quickly result in quite some files and start to eat up space.

TcPDF can send headers and data to view only the pdf in a browser without saving the file anywhere. This is basically what i want, but with the exception that the pdf data is embedded or a part of the server response. The html is needed, as the popup is widely used in our system and is just a fool-proof way for our staff to get the right documents to the right customers hassle-free.

I don't really mind setting up a cronjob to delete certain files older than an hour or so, but if it is possible to include the PHP file (or string data) from tcpdf some other way which doesn't need any additional cleanup, i would prefer it. Cronjobs and other "dependencies" could cause troubles in the future if someone else messes with settings they don't know all about.

Answer (score -1):

Just Base64 encode the PDF and set that as the value of the data property.

Comment: Is there something else to this, as i recall the object specification states data should be an url, and in fact i tried putting the pdf string into the data property but just get a blank page. I also tried both plain mpdf->output(null, 'S') and base64 encoding this without luck.